# Not able to create HIVE table with JSON format using SERDE

Tags: hadoop, hive

We are very new to Hadoop and Hive. We created normal Hive table and loaded data as well. But We are facing issue when we are creating table in Hive with JSON format. I have added serde jar also. We get the following error:

```
create table airline_tables(Airline string,Airlineid string,Sourceairport string,Sourceairportid string,Destinationairport string,`Destinationairportid string,Codeshare string,Stop string,Equipment String)` ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.JsonSerde'`location '/home/hduser/part-000';`

FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.NullPointerException
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

Location is HDFS.
I am using Hive-0.9.0 and hadoop 1.0.1.

Comment: Do you add `hive-contrib-*.jar` to `hive.aux.jars.path` ?

Comment: I have added jar path as well..                                HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=/usr/local/hadoop/hive-0.9.0/lib

Answer (score 2):

As i can see. You are using the native table of hive. So in that case you need to load the data in the table. If you dont want to load the data then you just put the path of that particular location in the table creation script. So, i think you missed the keyword "**EXTERNAL**" again create the table like this. create external table airline_tables(blah blah.....)